# How to use lateral view explode in Hive for XML data format?

Tags: xml, parsing, hadoop, hive, explode

I am trying to load sales data which is in XML format to the Hive table.
Below is a small sample of the data.

I am aware that I can load the data below to Hive if I separate it to several tables and then join them as required. But just wanted to know if I can load them in a single table and the expected output should look like the screenshot attached.

Please help me with the table structure I should use and how can I use the lateral view explode option effectively to achieve this.

Sample data:

```
  <Store>
    <Version>1.1</Version>
    <StoreId>16695</StoreId>    
    <Bskt>
      <TillNo>4</TillNo>
      <BsktNo>1753</BsktNo>
      <DateTime>2017-10-31T11:19:34.000+11:00</DateTime>
      <OpID>50056</OpID>
      <Itm>
        <ItmSeq>1</ItmSeq>
        <GTIN>29559</GTIN>
        <ItmDsc>CHOCALATE</ItmDsc>
      <ItmProm>
          <PromCD>CM</PromCD>
        </ItmProm>
      </Itm>
      <Itm>
        <ItmSeq>2</ItmSeq>
        <GTIN>59653</GTIN>
        <ItmDsc>CORN FLAKES</ItmDsc>
      </Itm>
        <Itm>
        <ItmSeq>3</ItmSeq>
        <GTIN>42260</GTIN>
        <ItmDsc> MILK CHOCOLATE 162GM</ItmDsc>
        <ItmProm>
          <PromCD>MTSRO</PromCD>
          <OfferID>11766</OfferID>
        </ItmProm>
      </Itm>
    </Bskt>
    <Bskt>
      <TillNo>5</TillNo>
      <BsktNo>1947</BsktNo>
      <DateTime>2017-10-31T16:24:59.000+11:00</DateTime>
      <OpID>50063</OpID>
      <Itm>
        <ItmSeq>1</ItmSeq>
        <GTIN>24064</GTIN>
        <ItmDsc>TOMATOES 2KG</ItmDsc>
        <ItmProm>
          <PromCD>INSTORE</PromCD>
        </ItmProm>
      </Itm>
      <Itm>
        <ItmSeq>2</ItmSeq>
        <GTIN>81287</GTIN>
        <ItmDsc>ROTHMANS BLUE</ItmDsc>
        <ItmProm>
          <PromCD>TF</PromCD>
        </ItmProm>
      </Itm>
    </Bskt>
  </Store>
```

Desired Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He6aX.png)

Table structure:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS POC_BASKET_ITEM_PROMO (
`Version` string,
`StoreId` string,
`DateTime` array<string>,
`BsktNo` array<double>,
`TillNo` array<int>,
`Item_Seq_num` array<int>,
`GTIN` array<string>,
`ItmDsc` array<string>,
`Promo_CD` array<string>,
`Offer_ID` array<int>
)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (

"column.xpath.Version"="/Store/Version/text()",
"column.xpath.StoreId"="/Store/StoreId/text()",
"column.xpath.DateTime"="/Store/Bskt/DateTime/text()",
"column.xpath.BsktNo"="/Store/Bskt/BsktNo/text()",
"column.xpath.TillNo"="/Store/Bskt/TillNo/text()",
"column.xpath.Item_Seq_num"="/Store/Bskt/Itm/ItmSeq/text()",
"column.xpath.GTIN"="/Store/Bskt/Itm/GTIN/text()",
"column.xpath.ItmDsc"="/Store/Bskt/Itm/ItmDsc/text()",
"column.xpath.Promo_CD"="/Store/Bskt/Itm/ItmProm/PromCD/text()",
"column.xpath.Offer_ID"="/Store/Bskt/Itm/ItmProm/OfferID/text()"
)

STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat' 
    LOCATION 'hdfs://namenode:8020/DEV/TEST/nanda_test'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
    "xmlinput.start"="<Store","xmlinput.end"="</Store>"
);
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WhUe.png)

Tried below query to read the data, It is not showing the results in the way i want.

```
select Version,StoreId,basket_dtm,basket_number,till_number from POC_BASKET_ITEM_PROMO
    LATERAL VIEW explode(DateTime) table1 as basket_dtm 
    LATERAL VIEW explode(BsktNo) table2 as basket_number
    LATERAL VIEW explode(TillNo) table3 as till_number;
```

Results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AUpI.png)

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you getting any error?

Comment: I have created the table structure as above and loaded all the data in a single row. Now i need to explode the arrays correctly to get the output as attached in the screenshot. I am not familiar with the explode options, just wondering how i can do it

Comment: Is there any way that I can use the XSD schema file of an XML and load the data in HIve tables. Like we do for AVRO files with AVRO schema? If that is possible, it would be great.

Comment: I believe that i need to make my query better to get the desired output, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode for array object works like cross join. 
So if you have 3 columns with each containing array with 2 elements, applying explode on all the columns will give you 8 rows.

You can't map one object from array to another.

Actually you can by using `posexplode` which gives you `index` for each element. which you can use to join based on condition.  However, that' tricky when you have multiple columns and the array size is different for each column.

**Solution**

- Use `posexplode` if you have less column to explode and array size is same.  for your case this is not going to work. So
- **Store XML as Complex Data Type** : Store your whole XML as a complex data type (not just array), I am talking about creating a `struct` based on your xml. 
  If you don't have much complex xml, you can achieve this. However `xmlSerde` is not as good as `JSONserde` when it comes to converting file to complex data type.

So in your case **best solution would** be.

- Convert your XML to JSON. You can use `NiFi` or some other technology for that.
- Create Hive table using `JSONserde` and load this file.
- Create a view as per your requirement.

**JSON for Your XML**

```
{"Version":"1.1","StoreId":"16695","Bskt":[{"TillNo":"4","BsktNo":"1753","DateTime":"2017-10-31T11:19:34.000+11:00","OpID":"50056","Itm":[{"ItmSeq":"1","GTIN":"29559","ItmDsc":"CHOCALATE","ItmProm":{"PromCD":"CM"}},{"ItmSeq":"2","GTIN":"59653","ItmDsc":"CORNFLAKES"},{"ItmSeq":"3","GTIN":"42260","ItmDsc":"MILKCHOCOLATE162GM","ItmProm":{"PromCD":"MTSRO","OfferID":"11766"}}]},{"TillNo":"5","BsktNo":"1947","DateTime":"2017-10-31T16:24:59.000+11:00","OpID":"50063","Itm":[{"ItmSeq":"1","GTIN":"24064","ItmDsc":"TOMATOES2KG","ItmProm":{"PromCD":"INSTORE"}},{"ItmSeq":"2","GTIN":"81287","ItmDsc":"ROTHMANSBLUE","ItmProm":{"PromCD":"TF"}}]}]}
```

`JsonSerde` might give your error if you have tabs or other white spaces in your file. So it's always best to remove them.

**Hive Table**

```
create external table temp.test_json
(
Version string,
StoreId string,
Bskt array<struct<
                    BsktNo:string,
                    DateTime:string,
                    OpID:string,
                    TillNo:string,
                    Itm:array<struct<
                                        GTIN:string,
                                        ItmDsc:string,
                                        ItmSeq:string,
                                        ItmProm:struct<
                                                        OfferID:string,
                                                        PromCD:string
                                                        >

                                    >
                            >
                >
            >
)
row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
location '/tmp/test_json/table/';
```

[image]
**Create View**

```
SELECT Version,
         StoreId,
         basket.bsktno,
         basket.tillno,
         basket.`datetime`,
         item.itmseq,
         item.itmdsc,
         item.gtin,
         item.itmprom.offerid,
         item.itmprom.promcd
FROM temp.test_json 
lateral view explode(bskt) b AS basket 
lateral view explode(basket.itm) i AS item
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for detailed solution. I tested it and it worked perfectly fine.
I tried a similar approach to read the data from the XML directly with XML serde.

My challenges:

```
1)XML to JSON conversion takes additional development efforts and we don't have Apache Nifi installation parcels in Cloudera by default, we need to install it with custom parcels.
2) My data will definitely have spaces/tab spaces in it, especially in 'Item description' field.We need to load the data with the same names as we receive. So converting to JSON and use the 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' didn't help. Queries failed with errors as suggested by you.
```

Below is the Hive table structure and the query I am using to read the data.
I am able to explode the first level array (Bskt) successfully without any issues.

But when i try to explode the second level array (Itm) it returns NULL results for all the fields in 'Itm'.

Is there any issue with my query or the table structure itself?

```
create external table nanda_scan_xml  (
  Version string,
  StoreId string,
  Bskt array<struct<
                    Bskt:struct<
                                DateTime:string,
                                TillNo:string,
                                BsktNo:string,
                                Itm:array<struct<
                                                Itm:struct<
                                                    ItmSeq:string,      
                                                    GTIN:string,        
                                                    ItmDsc:string,      
                                                    DeptCD:string,      
                                                    ItmCD:string,       
                                                    SalesQTY:string,        
                                                    SalesExGST:string,      
                                                    Points:string,      
                                                    CostExGST:string,       
                                                    GSTRate:string,     
                                                    DiscAmtExGST:string,        
                                                    ItmProm:struct<     
                                                                    PromCD:string,      
                                                                    OfferID:string      
                                                                  >
                                                              >
                                                     >
                                            >
                                >
                    >
            >
)
row format serde 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
with serdeproperties 
(
    "column.xpath.Version"       = "/Store/Version/text()",
    "column.xpath.StoreId"       = "/Store/StoreId/text()",
    "column.xpath.Bskt"  = "/Store/Bskt"

)
stored as 
inputformat     'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
outputformat    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat' 
LOCATION 'hdfs://namenode/LandingArea/Sources/SCANP/IGA_SCAN/STAGING/'
tblproperties 
(
    "xmlinput.start"    = "<Store>",
    "xmlinput.end"      = "</Store>"
);
```

Query:

1)For Bskt which works fine:

```
SELECT  Version,
        StoreId,
        basket.Bskt.DateTime,
        basket.Bskt.bsktno,
        basket.Bskt.tillno
FROM eim_stg.nanda_scan_xml
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(Bskt) b AS basket;
```

Results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrWPA.png)
2) When trying two lateral view explode in a single query:

```
SELECT  Version,
        StoreId,
        basket.Bskt.DateTime,
        basket.Bskt.bsktno,
        basket.Bskt.tillno,
        item.Itm.ItmSeq,
        item.Itm.ItmDsc,
        item.Itm.GTIN,
        item.Itm.itmprom.OfferID,
        item.Itm.itmprom.PromCD 
FROM eim_stg.nanda_scan_xml
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(Bskt) b AS basket
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(basket.Bskt.Itm) i AS item limit 100;
```

Results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x09t9.png)

3) Query:

```
SELECT  Version,
        StoreId,
        basket.Bskt.DateTime,
        basket.Bskt.bsktno,
        basket.Bskt.tillno,
        item.Itm.ItmSeq,
        item.Itm.ItmDsc,
        item.Itm.GTIN,
        item.Itm.itmprom.OfferID,
        item.Itm.itmprom.PromCD 
FROM eim_stg.nanda_scan_xml
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(Bskt) b AS basket
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(basket.Itm) i AS item limit 100;
```

Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFARa.png)

Comment: if you are able to get the xml table with complex data type. no issue. it's just XML serde is not as mature as JSON